# Package pgfkeys Error on TeXstudio, but no error on Overleaf

Tags: texstudio, pgfkeys, tkz-euclide

I've tried to use the code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528554/292801) by @AlainMatthes in TeXstudio, but I've got this error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tkzcircle/radius' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \tkzDefCircle[radius](O_2,C_1)
```

Then updated both MikTex and TeXstudio to the latest versions and I'm still getting the same error.

Then I tested it on Overleaf and it works fine there. Why it doesn't work on TeXstudio?

Log file part around the error:

```
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 24.

Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tkzcircle/radius' and I am goi
ng to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.61  \tkzDefCircle[radius](O_2,C_1)
                                    
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endpgfpicture ...globally \endgroup \hss \egroup 
                                                  \pgf@restore@layerlist@fro...
l.77  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Log file part from `\listfiles` using TeXstudio (the one that gives error):

```
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020/03/25>
 ***********

 *File List*
standalone.cls    2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2023/04/15 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
 xkeyval.sty    2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tkz-euclide.sty     2023/10/20 5.03c for pure Euclidean Geometry 
    tikz.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
     pgf.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  pgfrcs.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  xcolor.sty    2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
mathcolor.ltx
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  pgffor.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
     xfp.sty    2023-10-10 L3 Floating point unit
   expl3.sty    2023-10-23 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2023-10-23 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  xpatch.sty    2020/03/25 v0.3a Extending etoolbox patching commands
  xparse.sty    2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
tkz-euclide.cfg
tkz-tools-eu-base.tex
tkz-tools-eu-utilities.tex
tkz-tools-eu-BB.tex
tkz-obj-eu-grids.tex
tkz-lib-eu-marks.tex
tkz-tools-eu-text.tex
tkz-lib-eu-shape.tex
tkz-obj-eu-axesmin.tex
tkz-tools-eu-colors.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
tkz-draw-eu-points.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-by.tex
tkz-tools-eu-math.tex
tkz-tools-eu-intersections.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-with.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-spc.tex
tkz-tools-eu-angles.tex
tkz-obj-eu-circles.tex
tkz-obj-eu-circles-by.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-rnd.tex
tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex
tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex
tkz-obj-eu-triangles.tex
tkz-draw-eu-lines.tex
tkz-draw-eu-circles.tex
tkz-draw-eu-ellipses.tex
tkz-draw-eu-polygons.tex
tkz-draw-eu-angles.tex
tkz-draw-eu-sectors.tex
tkz-draw-eu-compass.tex
tkz-draw-eu-show.tex
tkz-draw-eu-protractor.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
 ***********
```

Log file part from `\listfiles` using Overleaf (no error):

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./output.aux)

 *File List*
standalone.cls    2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' class
 article.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tkz-euclide.sty     2022/02/25 4.051b for pure Euclidean Geometry 
    tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
     pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  xcolor.sty    2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
mathcolor.ltx
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgffor.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
     xfp.sty    2022-06-22 L3 Floating point unit
   expl3.sty    2022-08-05 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2022-08-05 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
tkz-euclide.cfg
tkz-tools-eu-base.tex
tkz-tools-eu-utilities.tex
tkz-tools-eu-BB.tex
tkz-obj-eu-grids.tex
tkz-lib-eu-marks.tex
tkz-tools-eu-text.tex
tkz-lib-eu-shape.tex
tkz-obj-eu-axesmin.tex
tkz-tools-eu-colors.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
tkz-tools-eu-math.tex
tkz-tools-eu-intersections.tex
tkz-tools-eu-angles.tex
tkz-obj-eu-compass.tex
tkz-obj-eu-circles.tex
tkz-obj-eu-circles-by.tex
tkz-obj-eu-draw-angles.tex
tkz-obj-eu-draw-circles.tex
tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines.tex
tkz-obj-eu-draw-polygons.tex
tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex
tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-by.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-rnd.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-spc.tex
tkz-obj-eu-points-with.tex
tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex
tkz-obj-eu-protractor.tex
tkz-obj-eu-sectors.tex
tkz-obj-eu-show.tex
tkz-obj-eu-triangles.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Have you updated miktex **both** in user and system mode? Otherwise, this is impossible to debug without having more data (a log and a \listfiles output).

Comment: If you mean if I did it also for admin then yes (nothing additional was updated). Added log file (in 2 parts since there is 30k char limit).

Comment: I get an error also with overleaf, unless I choose TeXlive 2022 or older. Likely some recent update of `tkz-euclide` broke something.

Comment: BTW: the needed part of the log is basically around the error *and* the output of the `\listfiles` command you should add at the end of preamble to have all the versions of the package used, so you can trim it down... please do. Anyway, I can confirm the error as @campa said --- maybe you can report an issue to `tkz-euclide`

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the tips, now posted just the part around the error.  Also posted the result from \listfiles from log files.

Comment: On overleaf you are using an old version `2022/02/25 4.051b`, with `4.2` there have apparently been major changes. This being said, it would be better to inform the author and maybe ping him on the question you link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a version problem. I assume that the version of tkz-euclide on Overleaf is not recent and that is why there is no error.

In the new version the `radius` option no longer exists. A circle is defined by its centre and a point, so just comment out this line

```
 % \tkzDefCircle[radius](O_2,C_1)
```